# Preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am facing following problem. Let's assume that my code looks like that

```
#define Function1 FunctionOne
#define Function2 FunctionTwo
#define CALL_FUNCTION ( FunctionName ) \
      SOMEOBJ someObject....
      someObject->FunctionName();
```

Now the problem is that I want to check what the function name is and depending on that I want to use different `SOMEOBJ`. So for a call of

```
CALL_FUNCTION(Function1)
```

following code will be called

```
  SOMEOBJ someObj...
  someObj->FunctionOne();
```

but for

```
 CALL_FUNCTION(Function2)
  ....
  SOMEOBJ2 someObj...
  someObj->FunctionOne();
```

Comment: It seems to me that macros are not the right tool for this job.

Comment: An [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I've ever seen one. What is it you really want to do, the thing you're trying to achieve by those macros?

Comment: I bet, it's impossible!

Comment: @9dan: Oh, if you squint enough I am sure this does look like a hammer that could be nailed with the macro hammer… even if in reality the problem is really a tree, but if you hammer hard enough who knows, you might be able to drive the tree into the wall.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to discourage you from using my answer. Like the comments say, you are probably shooting for the wrong solution to your problem.

As purpose for learning I want to provide you a macro solution:

```
struct SOMEOBJ1 {
    void FunctionOne() { std::cout << "SOMEOBJ1 FunctionOne"; }
};

struct SOMEOBJ2 {
    void FunctionTwo() { std::cout << "SOMEOBJ2 FunctionTWO"; }
};

#define Function1 FunctionOne
#define Function2 FunctionTwo
#define CALL_FUNCTION( funcVersion ) \
{ \
    SOMEOBJ ## funcVersion someobj; \
    someobj.Function ## funcVersion (); \
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CALL_FUNCTION(1);
    CALL_FUNCTION(2);

    return 0;
}
```